# Java Split method strings into method name and argument

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I am writing a small programming language for a game I am making, this language will be for allowing users to define their own spells for the wizard entity outside the internal game code. I have the language written down, but I'm not entirely sure how to change a string like

```
setSpellName("Fireball")
setSplashDamage(32,5)
```

into an array which would have the method name and the arguments after it, like

```
{"setSpellName","Fireball"}
{"setSplashDamage","32","5"}
```

How could I do this using java's String.split or string regex's?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you pass a method to a method? If so, you'll need a parser.

Comment: What are allowed characters? Can there be spaces in names of spell like `"Foo Bar Baz"`? Can there be parenthesis in names like `"Fireball(small)"`? If yes what result you are expecting for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only interested in the function name and parameters I'd suggest scanning up to the first instance of ( and then to the last ) for the params, as so.

```
String input = "setSpellName(\"Fireball\")";
String functionName = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('('));
String[] params = input.substring(input.indexOf(')'), input.length - 1).split(",");
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the response.

Comment: @johnnic431 First, this doesn't compile!!!  Second, how does "String[] params = input.substring(input.indexOf(')'), input.length - 1).split(",");" get the parameters?

Comment: It might need some tweaking, I did this last night off the top of my head. It works as follows:

1) For the function name, we know function names can't contain braces, so this will take the string up to the value of the first open bracket, giving you the function name.
2) Same applies for the params, we start from inside the brackets and cut the string at the end, -1 to account for the bracket at the end. And then split everything inside by the comma to obtain the params.

Answer (score 1):

To capture the String

```
setSpellName("Fireball")
```

Do something like this:

```
String[] line = argument.split("(");
```

Gets you "setSpellName" at line[0] and "Fireball") at line[1]

Get rid of the last parentheses like this

```
line[1].replaceAll(")", " ").trim();
```

Build your JSON with the two "cleaned" Strings.

There's probably a better way with Regex, but this is the quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 1):

With `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()`, you can parse out the function and parameters.  Once you parse them out, apply the quotes are around each of them.  Then combine them all back together delimited by commas and wrapped in curly braces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList() {{
        add("setSpellName(\"Fireball\")");
        add("setSplashDamage(32,5)");
    }};

    for (String command : commands) {
        int openParen = command.indexOf("(");
        String function = String.format("\"%s\"", command.substring(0, openParen));
        String[] parameters = command.substring(openParen + 1, command.indexOf(")")).split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
            // Surround parameter with double quotes
            if (!parameters[i].startsWith("\"")) {
                parameters[i] = String.format("\"%s\"", parameters[i]);
            }
        }

        String combine = String.format("{%s,%s}", function, String.join(",", parameters));
        System.out.println(combine);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
{"setSpellName","Fireball"}
{"setSplashDamage","32","5"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using regex, use this Regex `"([\\w]+)\\(\"?([\\w]+)\"?\\)"`:

```
    String input = "setSpellName(\"Fireball\")";
    String pattern = "([\\w]+)\\(\"?([\\w]+)\"?\\)";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String[] matches;
    Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));

        String[] params = m.group(2).split(",");
        if (params.length > 1) {
            matches = new String[params.length + 1];
            matches[0] = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(params.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                matches[i + 1] = params[i];
            }
            System.out.println(String.join(" :: ", matches));
        } else {
            matches = new String[2];
            matches[0] = m.group(1);
            matches[1] = m.group(2);
            System.out.println(String.join(", ", matches));
        }
    }
```

> `([\\w]+)` is the first group to get the function name.
>
> `\\(\"?([\\w]+)\"?\\)` is the second group to get the parameters.

This is **[a Working DEMO](https://ideone.com/BXx51G)**.